# No audio output using raspberry pi and pygame.midi

Tags: python, audio, pi-2, midi, pygame

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 and a set of speakers connected to the 3.5mm headphone jack. I've got most audio coming out of my speakers by running 
`amixer set name='PCM Playback Route' 1`. `pygame.mixer` works absolutely wonderfully without doing anything special. However, when I try to run my `pygame.midi` code I hear nothing.

I don't think it's a problem with my code personally. If I run `python -m pygame.examples.midi --output`, I see the graphical piano, no errors are thrown, but I hear no audio out.

I'm running Ubuntu Mate on my pi, but [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=116715&p=856931) makes it seem like that's not the issue.

Comment: My code just reads input from my MIDI keyboard, and tries to play the output, I will post it on github if it is useful for resolving my issue

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by running `sudo apt-get install timidity` and then changing my outport port from 0 to 3.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with `pygame`. However, I found that my issue was completely unrelated. This may be the case for you as well.

The problem is likely not a product of an issue with the `pygame.midi`, so much as it lies with the fact that your raspberry pi may be configured to forward its audio output to the HDMI cable connection.

I found that a fix can be arranged with two simple commands:

Typing the following commands tells us what our audio output is configured to:

```
amixer cget name='PCM Playback Route'
```

My output was this: (your's should be similar)

```
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Route'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw------,values=1,min=0,max=2,step=0
  : values=0
```

If the last line (value) is 0, the audio output is configured to the HDMI. Changing this value to `1` can easily allow the sound output to go through the 3.5mm audio jack!

Do this using this command:

```
amixer cget name='PCM Playback Route' 1
```

And that is all that there should be to it!

Comment: it should be 'cset' instead of 'cget' in the last block of code :)

Answer (score 0):

Probable cause of the problem can be in the output port mismatch.

Type `aconnect -i` to display a list of the readable input ports. These are the ports which provide incoming MIDI data.

```
$ sudo aconnect -i
```

response should have something like:

```
client 0: 'System' [type=kernel]
     etc....
client 20: 'USB MIDI Interface' [type-kernel, card=1]
    0 'USB MIDI Interface MIDI 1'
```

Type `aconnect -o` to display a list of the writable output ports. These are the ports which send outgoing MIDI data.
Again; response should have something like:

```
  client 20: 'USB MIDI Interface' [type-kernel, card=1]
     0 'USB MIDI Interface MIDI 1'
```

Finally, type `aconnect 14:0 20:0` to establish a bridge between the RaspberryPi port [14] in my case and the MIDI OUT port [20] {my case}.

```
$ sudo aconnect 14:0 20:0
```

Type `aconnect -x` to remove all connections when finished. Individual connections can be removed using the -d option. If you ever need usage information about `aconnect`, just type `aconnect -h` or `man aconnect`.

Good Luck!

Comment: The OP solved the problem by running `sudo apt-get install timidity` and then changing the outport port from 0 to 3. Just read his old answer.